# Smooth Scrolling With Zero JavaScript? With Just One Line of CSS

Tags: javascript, css, typescript

How can i set smooth scrolling without JavaScript, just one line of CSS

Smooth scrolling on the website I’m creating.

So i have this project of creating a website and I don’t want to include much JavaScript on it so any tip to include smooth scrolling without JavaScript? With just one line of CSS rule

Answer (score 2):

The CSS line of code you looking for is:

```
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

Here are the other scroll behaviors you may want:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_scroll-behavior.php